# svchost.exe - Application Error on startup

Tags: windows-xp, svchost

I'm using Windows XP. During startup I get the following error:

> **svchost.exe - Application Error**
>
> The instruction at "0x7c901010" referenced memory at "0x00000b14". The memory could not be "read".

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Application Error]

No matter what button I click, the system hangs and I have to press the power button.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: upgrade the OS version to Win7/8. XP is out of support.

Comment: @magicandre1981 : I don't want any update support only solution for error.

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you get the same issue if you [start Windows in safe mode](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/boot_failsafe.mspx) or  [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310353/en-us)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried "Last Known Good Configuration", "Directory Service In Restore Mode" from boot-menu and "System-Restore" But Error remains constant. Then I tried to repair OS by Disk but same error displayed during repair!

So, Finally I re-installed (formatted and clean-install)OS from Disk. Now It is running properly. (It seems major error and I have to re-install).